# How do i implement effects in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, effects

What is the best and most efficient way to add effects to a game built with cocos2d?
I mean effects like an explosion.
Are they just animation / sprits?
If not, then what should i receive from the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `cocos2d project` which comes with library and in the top left drop down list you can choose `Particle System Test` and build it. So you will able to see all basic particle effects cocos2d has.

Also there is a nice application [ParticleDesigner](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/), where you can make your nice looking particles and generate a file to add to cocos2d project, it also has a lot of samples, so it would be good for you to download it and see.

And cocos2d supports animations as well, so you can make animations from frames, but of course in the case of explosions particles would look much better

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [CCParticleSystem](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_particle_system.html) and or [CCParticleSystemQuad](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_particle_system_quad.html). You or your designer can use tools like [ParticleDesigner](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) to create great looking particle effects.